# how to remove game objects after on overlap in LIBGDX game

Tags: java, android, game-design, libgdx

I have gold stars in my game that give score to game hero if the hero overlap with the star. What I want is to remove star once it overlap with hero object. 
I give score by checking overlap with this code

```
public void scorecount(Hero myhero){

            if (!star.isScored() && Intersector.overlaps(myhero.getBoundingBalloon(), star.getStarCircle())) 
    {

                addScore(1); // give one plus always
  star.setScored(true);


AssetLoader.coin.play();

}
```

Now once I give score and setScore true , i want to remove star.
How can I do that?
I tried for setvisible method but I dont know how to use it. Because just Calling star.setVisible() ask to create this method in star class. then in star class I dont know what should be given inside this method body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ArrayList` to store all your stars in. When collision is detected you remove star from array so the star is no longer updated.

So :

**create** :

```
ArrayList <Star> stars= new ArrayList<Star>();
```

**add the stars** :

```
stars.add (new Star (param1, param2));
```

**update** :

```
    for (int i = 0; i < stars.size(); i++) {
       star.get(i).update (param1, param2);
    }

        for (int i = 0; i < stars.size(); i++) {
          if (player.overlaps(stars.get(i)) { 
              // remove star from arraylist
              stars.remove(i);
              // another approach would be not to remove the star, but to respawn it
              // on a different position; it depends what your game logic require
              stars.get(i).respawn (param1, param2);
         }
            }
```